# PL/SQL: Creating trigger which validates column content

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I've got the following table in which I'm using Oracle SQL dev.

```
CREATE TABLE FAGFELT
(
book integer references BOOK (isbn),  
field varchar (255),
CONSTRAINT chk_field CHECK (field IN('databases', 'programmering', 'math', 'statistics', 'chemistry', 'physics'))  
);
```

I'm trying to make trigger which makes it only possible for a the book id can not be associated with more than three of the following constraints. In which the values should be atomic, like this 
[image: table view]

I'm clueless how this could be done being new to PL SQL, but I suspect I should try to make a compound trigger? I find the syntax quite tricky, and really don't know how I would make it work. I only know what the trigger should do, that being the validation of the insert of data and maybe throw an error message if the requirement isn't met.

Comment: Are you trying to use a trigger for this because it's a homework assignment and that is a requirement?  In practice, this is not something that you'd generally want to enforce via a trigger.

Comment: Your table is not Oracle syntax. Are you using Oracle and posted table definition from other DB or you're using other DB?

Comment: Primarly it's for a homework assignment and that being one of many requirements, but also in practice I'd say because I really want to get it. One of the student assistents recommended using a trigger to fulfill the requirement, and me not knowing any better I thought that would probly the way to go.

Comment: I thought I was using Oracle syntax, Kacper. I'm using SQL dev and yeah, I'm fairly new to SQL in general so I don't really know the difference between the different SQL syntax varients.

Comment: I'm not going to do your home work for you but yes you can obtain it with trigger doing `count(distinct field) where book = :new.book` in trigger on insert update and when it is 3 do not allow insert another value

Comment: Thank you, Kacper! I think this might be enough to point me at in the right direction.

Comment: @Kacper, this is perfectly valid Oracle syntax. It runs fine in my 11g instance. What do you think is wrong with it?

Comment: @JeffreyKemp references is really Oracle syntax? Also integer is valid however strange for Oracle.

Comment: @Kacper perhaps you should familiarise yourself with this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/toc.htm

Comment: @JeffreyKemp `  CREATE TABLE FAGFELT 
   ( BOOK NUMBER(*,0), 
     FIELD VARCHAR2(255 BYTE), 
  CONSTRAINT CHK_FIELD CHECK (field IN('databases', 'programmering', 'math', 'statistics', 'chemistry', 'physics')) ENABLE, 
  FOREIGN KEY (BOOK)
   REFERENCES BOOK (ISBN) ENABLE
   )` this is normal definition for that table. `references` next to column name I see first time. Oracle accepts it but please give me a source that say it is proper way. The same with integer.

Comment: @Kacper, do you need some private tuition on how to learn things for yourself? What is it about "I tested it, it works" and "here's a link to the docs" that just doesn't cut it for you?